# print loop numbers with a specified name in R

Tags: r, printing

I am running a simple for-loop in R, and try to print the loop numbers with names. For example,

```
   for(i in 1:3){
     print (i)
   }

   [1] 1
   [1] 2
   [1] 3
```

But I want the loop numbers printed with a name, and want to have the following print result:

```
   [1] replication=1
   [1] replication=2
   [1] replication=3
```

Can I realize this using the print() command? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "printed with a name", but you could use `paste0` with `noquote` to get your desired result.

```
for(i in 1:3) print(noquote(paste0("replication=", i)))
# [1] replication=1
# [1] replication=2
# [1] replication=3
```

Or, as suggested by @BondedDust in the comments, just use `cat`

```
for(i in 1:3) cat("replication=", i, "\n" sep = "")
# replication=1 
# replication=2 
# replication=3
```

Comment: Good point.  I was sticking to the OPs desire to use `print()`. Edited

Comment: yes! this is what I want to do. Thank you and @BondedDust